# Python requests.raise_for_status() exceptions find the output

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, output

```
res = requests.get(url=url, verify=False)
res.raise_for_status()

try:
   if "Unauthorised" in res.json()['msg']:
      return
except Exception as err:
   print(err)
```

What is the output if res gives response code 401, will the code in try be executed ?

What is the expected output of this snipptet ?

Comment: Check the `raise_for_status` [source code](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/requests/models/#Response.raise_for_status)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the output if res gives response code 401, will the code in try be executed ?

No; you'll get an exception from `res.raise_from_status()` before control reaches that try/except.

> What is the expected output of this snipptet ?

It will print an error message (but not handle it in any other way) if the response can't be parsed as JSON, or if it has not `msg` key, or if the `in` operator can't be used with whatever is in that `msg` key.

Comment: If the response returned by request.get() statement is not 200, then it will never come in the try/except block. Only for response 200,  the exceptions would be printed for cases you mentioned( response can't be parsed as JSON, or if it has not msg key, or if the in operator can't be used with whatever is in that msg key) 

correct ?

Comment: `raise_for_errors()` catches statuses >= 400, so "not 200" isn't exactly correct.